# Change color of every third card in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, background-color, android-cardview

I have implemented code for `CardView` using `RecyclerView`. 
My list has 15 items, now I want to change every odd `CardView` background color in the list.
Please provide the proper code for that as I am new in `CardView`.
I have tried simple odd even code for that.
Here is the code:

**in onBindViewHolder method:**

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv1.setText(result[position]);
    imageLoader.displayImage("drawable://" + imgs[position], holder.iv1, options);

    for(int i =0; i <= imgs.length;i+=2)
    {
        holder.cv1.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will change all the cardview background color.

Comment: if anybody still having this problem.. i have solved it.. do not use For loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use % operator.

**position % 2 == 0** should be used to change odd and even backgrounds.

If you want every third card to have a different background from others use: **position % 3 == 0**

pseudo code sample:

```
if((position % 2 == 0)){
     holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.list_even_color);
 }else{
     holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.list_odd_color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if(position%2==0){

        holder.rowLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color1));

    }else{
        holder.rowLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color2));

    }
}
```

// this code is for odd even row items.